# Skip and Abort Jenkins builds if new PR version is available

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I am using https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin for PR builds. Jenkins is set to scan PRs regularly.

Often it can happen that an open PR request will get regular updates. My job is scanning them and appending them to the queue and running them in order. This is a waste and I want to run only the latest PR version. In fact, if a job is running, I want to even abort and run the latest. Can I do this? How?

Thanks for the help folks!

Answer (score 0):

By chance we do the same, here's the code:

```
def kill_other_builds() {
    def jobname = env.JOB_NAME
    def my_buildnum = env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger()
    echo "Job is ${jobname}, build number is ${my_buildnum}"

    def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobname)
    for (build in job.builds) {
        this_buildnum = build.getNumber().toInteger()
        if (!build.isBuilding()) {
            println "Build ${this_buildnum} isn't building."
            continue; 
        }
        if (my_buildnum == this_buildnum)
        { 
            println "Build ${this_buildnum} is building and it's this build."
            continue; 
        }
        else if (my_buildnum < this_buildnum)
        { 
            errorMsg = "A newer build is already scheduled"
            currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"
            currentBuild.description = errorMsg
            error(errorMsg)
        }

        echo "Kill build ${build} number ${this_buildnum}."
        build.displayName += "(stopped by #${my_buildnum})"
        build.doStop()
        try {
            sleep 5
        } catch (err) {
            String errStr = err.toString()
            println errStr
        }
    }
}
```