# How do I stop a currently running jenkins build if a new build is triggered with same parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, parameterized, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a declarative pipeline in Jenkins which builds and pushes docker images to two different container registries. I have configured another freestyle job to lookout for any changes in a few branches and passes the branch name as parameter to declarative pipeline (Branch name is the only parameter for now).

Now, I want to abort the running build, if there's a new build triggered with the same Branch name (or same parameters). How can I do this in a declarative pipeline?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59195377/2047614

In your case need to compare parameters as well, see [Finding previous Jenkins job that had a specific param value, but without using `hudson.model.Hudson`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71028824/2047614)