# Finding previous Jenkins job that had a specific param value, but without using `hudson.model.Hudson`

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

#### Goal:

The end-goal is to find the ***latest*** build (not necessarily the previous build!) that had a parameter `MY_PARAM` value equal to the `MY_PARAM` value of the ***current*** build.

The reason for this is to mimic the "Back to normal" operation of the Slack Plugin behavior on Freestyle Jobs, but making it more specific to check the previous build with a particular param set.

For example, let's say we have this build history:

```
Build #300 - MY_PARAM=foo - SUCCESS
Build #301 - MY_PARAM=bar - SUCCESS
Build #302 - MY_PARAM=foo - SUCCESS
Build #303 - MY_PARAM=foo - FAILED
Build #304 - MY_PARAM=bar - FAILED
Build #305 - MY_PARAM=abc - SUCCESS
Build #306 - MY_PARAM=foo - SUCCESS
```

With the above job history, if we launch a new job (#307) with MY_PARAM=bar, I need to scan the most recent job with MY_PARAM=bar and check if it was successful or not (which in this case would have been build #304).

So, I wrote up some script (**it works fine**) to go in the `success{}` block of Pipeline `post{}` section:

```
script {
  def inst = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
  def project = null

  Boolean recovery = false
  Integer currentBuildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER

  inst.getItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob).each {
    if (it.displayName.equals(env.JOB_NAME)) {
      project = it
    }
  }

  def builds = project.getBuilds()

  for (build in builds) {
    Integer buildNumber = build.getNumber()

    // We don't care about the current build
    if (buildNumber == currentBuildNumber) { 
      continue
    }
    
    // Get any params
    def parameters = build.actions.find{ it instanceof ParametersAction }?.parameters
    // Find the param we care about
    def myParam = parameters?.find{ it.name == 'MY_PARAM' }?.value

    if (myParam == params.MY_PARAM) {
      // Mark recovery = true if the previous build with this param wasn't a success
      if (build.result.name != 'SUCCESS') {
        recovery = true
      }
      break
    }
  }
    
  // Causes java.io.NotSerializableException if not cleared
  builds = project = inst = null

  if (recovery == true) {
    // Does some stuff.... 
  }
```

**So, this works fine!** However, it seems like I may be overcomplicating and/or doing this wrong based on warnings I now see in settings.

##### Problems/Questions

- I had to approve many signatures to get this to work. Now my Jenkins settings is glaring red with "unsafe" script approval for `staticMethod hudson.model.Hudson getInstance` which doesn't feel right. I tried the "assuming permission check" but it didn't work. Should I worry about this? The Jenkins instance is access controlled.
- Is there an overall workaround to get the job/param data I need without using `hudson.model.Hudson getInstance` and without making the solution more complex (ex: w/o using shared libraries)?
- Is there overall a different/better way to meet my original goal? All I really need is the build history and the params + build result of each build.

[image: warning]

[image: script approvals]

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate builds of current project without accessing Hudson/Jenkins instance

```
def build = currentBuild.previousBuild()
while( build ) {
   ...do smth here
   def build = build.previousBuild()
}
```

https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#getPreviousBuild--

Comment: Thanks. So, you're saying I could keep iterating through the full history by continuing to call  `build.previousBuild()`, not necessarily on `currentBuild` but on any `build` object? I'll give this a shot, but if it works like that it sounds like it could be the win thanks.

Comment: right. i fixed the answer a bit

Comment: This seemed to allow me to iterate through the previous builds, however it breaks now when I try to get the params of that previous build object:  `def parameters = build.actions.find{ it instanceof ParametersAction }?.parameters` 
Now throws: 
`org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field `

Comment: I don't think you can get parameters from a `RunWrapper` object which is what `build` is in this case. 

https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-54535

Comment: you still able to access raw build : `build.getRawBuild().actions.find{...}`

Comment: Appreciate that, but approving getRawBuild() just brings me back to the original warning in settings about "may have introduced a security vulnerability"  which is what prompted this question in the first place. I'll keep hacking at it and may need to just settle having the warnings in settings and coach the team to ignore the warnings when seen.

Comment: Right. But original question was about `Hudson getInstance` which is `dangerous`. Other solution is to build own plugin. Or log all builds to a custom storage...

Comment: The UI also marks it as "dangerous" in red text. I ended up not fighting this in Groovy/Jenkins and will keep build state stored in a nosql store and be done with it. Thanks for all the help.